# SmtpException when trying to send Email

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I am writing a method for sending Emails for one of my projects. This method will be used to send Emails through a Exchange Server. But for now, I want to test it with a GMX account. I have gotten the settings right but I always get an exception.

```
        public static bool emailSenden(string strTo, string strSubject, string strContent)
        {               
            string strFrom = "abwesenheiten_datagroup@gmx.de";
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(strFrom, strTo, strSubject, strContent);

            string strHost = "mail.gmx.net";
            int port = 465;

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(strHost, port);

            string strUsername = "abwesenheiten_datagroup@gmx.de";
            string strPasswort = "pass";
            System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(strUsername, strPasswort);
            client.Credentials = credentials;
            client.EnableSsl = true;

            try
            {
                client.Send(mail);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

My Exception:

Access to a socket was invalid due to the access rights of the socket [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx].

Things I have tried:

- Setting different port.
- Removing port and set `EnableSsl` to False.
- Using different hosts (GMX, Web.de, etc.)

**EDIT:** Ok after disabling a setting in McAfee Anti Virus I get a different exception. Now it says:

"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a certain period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

Comment: Is this a desktop application? If so did you tried running application by clicking on run as administrator?

Comment: I run this from an ASP.NET application which uses IIS 5.1 with Windows Authentication. The account I use here is an admin.

Comment: Can you configure the same in OUTLOOK or any other similar desktop application like OUTLOOK?

Comment: Yes but it also doesn't work. Our exchange server is also only accessible through a proxy and I don't know how to set that up yet in C#.

Comment: Then first try setting up your outlook. Once you set it up successfully, you will get the required changes for setting up your C# code from Outlook.